# UIWebView delay in loading local content

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm displayed a small amount of local content in a UIWebView, roughly 3 paragraphs of text and one 100x100px image. When the UIWebView is pushed onto to the nav controller, it takes about half a second before the content is displayed. This occurs on the device, not in the simulator. Obviously the UIWebView needs to do some work before displaying the content, but is there some way I can do this before the pushed view appears? I have not had any luck doing this myself.

Here is where I'm creating and pushing the view controller which contains the UIWebView:

```
ArticleViewController* viewController = [[ArticleViewController alloc] init];
viewController.article = article;
[viewController view]; //touch the view so it gets loaded
[viewController loadWebView]; //load the web view content
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

And here is the `loadWebView` method:

```
-(void)loadWebView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString* content = article.content;

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                      <html><body style='background-color: transparent'><style type=""text/css"">body {font-family: helvetica; color: black; font-size: 10pt; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px}</style>\
                      %@<div style='text-align:center'><a href='13443574_9709e4cf37.jpg?photographer=test' style='-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);'><img src='13443574_9709e4cf37.jpg' height='160' width='230'></a></div></body></html>", content];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

Previously I had `[viewController loadWebView]` in the viewDidLoad method, but the result seems to be the same. A blank screen when the viewController is pushed, followed by the content loading half a second later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to make the user wait, the only question is: is it before or after the webview appears? If you're set on "before", then you should create the controller, load the web view, but wait to push it until the -webViewDidFinishLoad: delegate method fires. Once you receive that, you can push the view.

Answer (score 13):

## Problem Confirmed

I too see a half-second or more delay with a white screen before my [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) content appears. This happens only on the first use of a UIWebView during that run of the app. Successive appearances of UIWebView are nearly instantaneous. So it seems to me and other folk that the delay must be due to [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) libraries needing to load and initialize.

## Warm-up WebKit

You cannot eliminate the delay. But you can move that delay to the start of your app, to lessen the annoying effect of "blank screen" to your users. The trick is to load UIWebView with a bogus page off-screen, during your app's launch. Build a minimal [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) web page in a hard-coded string. I use a correct and valid HTML5 content to minimize the time taken by UIWebView/WebKit to analyze.

This technique works noticeably well on real hardware (*iPhone 3GS*), not just the *iOS Simulator*.

In my app delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), the bottom of the [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)-compliant code looks like this:

```
…
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Performance optimization: Warm up the UIWebView widget and its related WebKit libraries.
// We are choosing the trade-off between (A) a slight delay here during app launch to create and abandon a bogus UIWebView instance, and
// (B) a flash of white and noticeable delay as the UINavigationController slides in from the right the first UIWebView we display during the app run.
UIWebView* bogusWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
NSString* html = @"<!doctype html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>blah</title></head><body><p>bogus content</p></body></html>";
[bogusWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; // Load the page.
bogusWebView = nil; // Not really needed, but self-documents that we intend to discard this object.

return YES;
```

This technique seems to reduce most but not quite all of the approximate half-second delay during the user's first appearance of UIWebView on screen. I conclude that most of the delay is due to WebKit warming up, but there must be some overhead related to graphically presenting a UIWebView on-screen. If so, we cannot eliminate that remaining overhead with off-screen work. But nevertheless, this technique eliminates *most* of the initial delay. So the user's first impression of my app won't be "slow".

Comment: Great answer! This also works for WKWebView, although I found doing the initialisation in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` didn't work and I had to put the code inside a viewController which appears before the web view.

Comment: Awesome... Save my day.. Thank You.