# pushViewController Extremely slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

What could cause pushViewController to be extremely slow? (it takes 30+seconds for the new view to appear)

Basically, I'm doing something like this:

```
SecondViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"correctID"];
vc.something = something;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
CLS_LOG(@"Pushed Controller...");
```

and i'm logging at the beginning of viewdidload inside the second view controller.
I'm not subclassing other methods.

Between Pushed Controller... and the next log from viewdidload there's a huge delay.

How would you debug this?

I already tried with the TimeProfiler but apparently it shows nothing.

Comment: I'd guess that something in your SecondViewController's `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, or `viewDidAppear` methods are taking a very long time. Just for debugging, try commenting out their content and see which is causing your issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're running that code in the main thread?  Show us more context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Had similar problem before, try the following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // your navigation controller action goes here
});
```

Comment: You're right, that did the trick. I was not running that code in the main thread.

Answer (score 8):

Dino's answer saved my life.  He got my upvote.  I'm just adding this for modern swift users.

```
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }
```

Comment: Anyone still having the issue after doing this?  I am.  But I think it has to do with pushing to a WebKit view.  Extremely frustrated.

Comment: @tjberte, have you set up the push to happen after the web call returns or before?

Comment: Might need a little more detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852257/uiwebview-delay-in-loading-local-content

Comment: Close to what I did.  I loaded a UIView in the first load, then loaded WebView with viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the background color e.g. `vc.view.backgroundColor = .white` solves the issue for me.